# CreatePerOwinContext causes 404 response in owin self hosted web-api

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, owin, asp.net-web-api2, self-hosting

I have a self-hosted asp.net web api. I have several api controllers which work fine. All requestes reach api methods and responces reach clients.
Now I try to add authorization for the web-api.

I have change my startup config by adding AUTH SECTION.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartOptions startOptions = new StartOptions();
            startOptions.Urls.Add("https://*:44305/");
            startOptions.Urls.Add("http://*:9001/");
            using (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<dobStartUp>(startOptions))
            {
              //...
            }
       }
    public class dobStartUp
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //----AUTH SECTION---
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
           // PublicClientId = "self";
           // OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
           // {
           //     TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
           //     Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
           //     AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
           //     AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
           //     AllowInsecureHttp = true
           // };
           // app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
            //-------------

            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver),new dobAssembliesResolver());
            config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
           // config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Common.dobJsonContractResolver();
           var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IdobRDBRepository, dobRDBRepository>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IResourcesContentRepository, AS3ContentRepository>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
            SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
            traceWriter.IsVerbose = false;
            traceWriter.MinimumLevel = TraceLevel.Debug;
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

When I use app.CreatePerOwinContext in auth-section ,Methods for creating appDbContext and appUserManager are invoked but i have 404 responces on every api method. When I dont call these CreatePerOwinContext  methods every works as usual. I know that I can use my IoC container for making instances of dbContext and userManager but i want to understand my current problem with app.CreatePerOwinContext and 404 responces.
Thanks everybody in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of 404 responce. It's beacause of custom assemblies resolver. I have controllers in seperate dll that's why i used custom assemblies resolver where i manualy load assembly with api-controllers. That worked fine till I used only web-api in owin pipeline. 
The next I tried to add authorization to web api - I used [CreatePerOwinContext] and [app.UseOAuthBearerTokens] so I added middlewares. It loads referenced assemblies before web-api starts create any controllers. If I have understand right while debuging I had twice loaded api-controllers assemblies. So it caused collisions in time of creating an instances of controllers.

Comment: I'm not sure what your solution was.  Can you paste your new code that works?  Thanks!